# Avoid the for loop

Tags: r, encoding

I would like to compute the product between the each row of a matrix x with itself. And then sum the result of all these products. The result is a scalar. I make the following coda that works but is not efficient. Can someone help me to avoid the for loop?

```
for(i in 1:nrow(x){
   resid2[i] <- t(x[i,])%*% x[i,]
  }
  V = sum(resid2)/
```

Comment: `sum(apply(x, 1, function(z) z%*%z))` ?

Comment: @EvanFriedland exactly, i will accept your answer, but explain the code please in the answer!

Comment: I made an answer. You may also speed up your loop if you just initialize your resid2 vector to start. Let me know if you need more of an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer that swaps the for loop out for the `apply` family.

`sum(apply(x, margin = 1, function(z) z%*%z))`

The `apply` function takes the matrix `x`, `margin = 1` means for each row (as opposed to `margin = 2` which means each column). So, for each row in `x` run a function that multiplies that row by itself: `function(z) z%*%z`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is just the sum of squares of all elements of the matrix.

```
V = sum(x^2)
```

which can also be calculated via matrix multiplication as:

```
V = crossprod(as.vector(x))
```

The intermediate vector `resid2` can be calculated as

```
resid2 = rowSums(x^2)
V = sum(resid2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to loop at all. `mat %*% mat` should do it:

```
mat <- matrix(seq.int(9), nrow=3)

mat
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    2    5    8
## [3,]    3    6    9

mat %*% mat
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   30   66  102
## [2,]   36   81  126
## [3,]   42   96  150
```

Comment: x <- matrix(seq.int(9), nrow=3)
resid2 <- rep(NA,nrow(x))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  resid2[i] <- t(x[i,])%*% x[i,]
}
V = sum(resid2)



sum(apply(x, 1, function(z) z%*%z))

Comment: this should be the result!